# Convolving a signal with the impulse response of the channel

Tags: discrete-signals, channelcoding

For a complex signal **x** to be transmitted over a channel with complex impulse response **h**, **x** will be convolved with **h**. What will the mathematical operation done in the reveiver to cancel the effect of **h**? I am confused because I have a code in which **x** is multiplied with **h** in the transmitter, and in the receiver, the received signal is multiplied by conjucate **h** and divided by **h** squared.

Comment: at the receiver, an equalization operation is performed. See e.g. http://wireless.ece.ufl.edu/twong/Notes/Comm/ch4.pdf . What you describe actually sounds, as if the channel and signal were in the frequency domain and the convolution theorem was applied.

Comment: I think what you are describing is a matched filter (assuming the impulse response was time reversed as well as conjugated and normalized). This approach should maximize the SNR of the signal, but it doesn't guarantee ISI-free communication. To make such guarantees, one would usually employ an equalizer optimized in same way (e.g., MSE criterion or BER criterion).